# What force causes tangential acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

I believe the static friction is responsible for the centripetal acceleration whereas kinetic friction is responsible for the tangential acceleration. But the answer key states otherwise and says it's option C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only static friction involved here. No other forces in this plane, so static friction must cause both centripetal and tangential accelerations.

- If static friction points directly towards the centre, then all of it contributes to the **centripetal acceleration** (and $a_{tan}=0$, the car has constant speed).
- If it points along with the car's motion, then all of it contributes to the **tangential acceleration** (and $a_{cen}=0$, the car doesn't turn (no circular motion)).

At any other angle, it contributes a bit to both (the car both speeds up *and* turns). Split the force into components, and the radial component contributes to the centripetal acceleration, while the tangential component contributes to the tangential acceleration.

Comment: I see my mistake, sir. I would like to share a bit of insight I got while going through this question. The fact why kinetic friction cannot act. I believe that if kinetic friction acts the wheels don't undergo pure rolling

Answer (score 0):

There is only one net horizontal force exerted by the ground on the tire.  This net force is comprised of components in the circumferential and radial directions, and is provided by friction.  The tire will skid (i.e., static friction will be exceeded) if the net force is greater than normal upward force from the ground times the coefficient of static friction.